# Don't mark @property-read as read-only

Tags: phpstorm

When I'm writing code, PhpStorm marks properties that are defined with `@property-read` as read-only, and shows an error.
Normally I would say: good behaviour.

But for now I'm writing unit tests, and some tests are actually testing if the property really is read-only. For that I need to set the property in the test (and expect an exception).
Everything works fine, but it just isn't really that nice to develop in an IDE that is showing errors everywhere, while they're intended in this case.

Is there a way to disable the read-only inspection for a specific folder (the test folder)? Or if this is not possible, is there a way to disable the read-only inspection?
Either way: I cannot find it in the settings screen.

Comment: Such check is either done on lower lever Parser/Lexer (where you cannot suppress/ignore error) or via some another functionality (not usual Inspection which you can easily suppress). So -- nope -- I see no ways how it can be suppressed right now.

Comment: Have the same problem ;(

Comment: I've created and issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72275/Possibility-to-disable-read-only-inspection-for-writable-class-property-solely-marked-with-read-only